# extract different number of values from a string and assign it to variables with bash

Tags: string, bash, variables, extract

I have this string

```
OK - C: Total=39.90GB, Used=27.51GB (69.0%), Free=12.39GB (31.0%)     OK - F: Total=230.00GB, Used=214.86GB (93.4%), Free=15.14GB (6.6%)     OK - G: Total=10.00GB, Used=4.03GB (40.3%), Free=5.97GB (59.7%)     OK - H: Total=510.00GB, Used=492.82GB (96.6%), Free=17.17GB (3.4%)     |'C: Space'=27.51GB; 'C: Utilisation'=69.0%; 'F: Space'=214.86GB; 'F: Utilisation'=93.4%; 'G: Space'=4.03GB; 'G: Utilisation'=40.3%; 'H: Space'=492.82GB; 'H: Utilisation'=96.6%;
```

These are the drives on a windows machine extracted with nagios..so the number and the letters may change from string to string..i would like to extract from this type of string the number of the drive (4 in this case), the letters (C F G H) and the various total and free values and assign all of this to different variables with bash..it's seems very tricky to me..is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please indicate the definition of the format of the string. I understand that the string is made of two parts separated by `|`; the second part is not interesting and it is to be discarded. The first part consists of zero or more drive description parts, each having the format `OK - <d>: Total=<n1>GB, Used=<n2>GB (<p1>%), Free=<n3>GB (<p2>%)`, with *d* being a drive letter, and *n1*, *n2*, *n3*, *d1*, *d2* being floating point numbers in American format. Is this correct?

Comment: It's a matter of fun with awk command and print/assign requested field to variable.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: Yep, i'd like a result like this.. Count=4 CTotal=39 CFree=12 FTotal=230 FFree=15 GTotal=10 GFree=5 HTotal=510 HFree=17

Answer (score 0):

An associative array would be much more manageable with this kind of data, rather than a bunch of individual variable names

```
str="OK - C: Total=39.90GB, ..."

Count=0
declare -A Total Free

while read drive; read total; read free; do 
    ((Count++))
    Total[$drive]=$total
    Free[$drive]=$free
done < <(
    grep -oP '(?<=OK - )[A-Z]|(?<=Total=)\d+|(?<=Free=)\d+' <<<"$str"
)

declare -p Count Total Free
```

```
declare -- Count="4"
declare -A Total='([C]="39" [F]="230" [G]="10" [H]="510" )'
declare -A Free='([C]="12" [F]="15" [G]="5" [H]="17" )'
```

`grep -o` is the magic that extracts the drive letter and the total and free values from the string.
I'm assuming that Total=x always appears before Free=y

With the array, you can now do:

```
for drive in "${!Total[@]}"; do
    printf "%s, total=%d, free=%d\n" "$drive" "${Total[$drive]}" "${Free[$drive]}"
done
```

and you don't have to know what the actual drive letters are beforehand.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to know the variables for any drive present..when i have the data for any drive present i will add in the script the mode to calculate the free space against a value based on the disk size and finally report out all of them with the Ok or Attention state (for example..a disk with 5Gb free is Ok if the size of the disk is 30Gb, but is in Attention state if the disk size is 200Gb)

Comment: I don't understand your concern: this method *does* give you the variables for any drive present. Does this not work for other input values you did not show?